# Bootstrap 4 - how to add a toggle inline to a form input label

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have the following Bootstrap 4 form

```
<div class="form-layout">
            <div class="row mg-b-25">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-control-label">Status: <span class="tx-danger">*</span></label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="status" value="" placeholder="Enter status">
                    </div>
                </div><!-- col-4 -->
      </div>
</div>
```

[image]

What I want to achieve is the following.

[image]

I'm using this for toggles: `https://simontabor.com/labs/toggles/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the Estatus and the toggle inside a `div` and then use the Bootstrap 4 flexbox classes `d-flex` and `justify-content-between` to achieve it.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kongallis/r5pc2nq3/9

Toggle code source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp